# [root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install MySQL on Redhat 7 on AWS and Google drive, however after installing the mysql-server 5.7, I recieve on both the same error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I didn't do any change or update, I just recieve this error after running my first mysql command on the shell.

I tried to start using mysql-init file, and it failed. Also, the `mysqld_safe` is not found.

Comment: Did you configure your user and password to your mysql?

Comment: how to configure it? I tried mysqladmin but still no result.

Comment: I found the root password created in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need admin access so just do `sudo mysql` ^_^